# What does it mean if a girl puts "есть подруга" in Семейное положение?

Tags: словоупотребление

I google it and found the word "подруга" means "girlfriend". Does it mean "girlfriend" or "a friend who is a female"? If it means a friend who is a female, it seems weird that she put "есть подруга" in Семейное положение right? And this girl is not a lesbian too. So I really don't understand this.

Or could "подруга" mean something else like, a boyfriend or lover? Could it mean she has a boyfriend?

Comment: it's ambiguous and can mean both, as a friend and as a partner, although i'm not aware of how this is viewed in lesbian circles, for the purpose of marital status indication it's simple, it will be either **супруга** or **гражданская супруга** if marriage is unofficial, but never **подруга**... otherwise it's not clear what and whom you specifically refer to in phrases "she put", " this girl"... still a possible duplicate of a few older topics https://russian.stackexchange.com/search?q=девушка+подруга

Comment: "she put" and "this girl" are the same girl. She wrote "есть подруга" in marital status , and she is not a lesbian. So, I don't understand what she meant by that. However, thank you so much for answering.

Comment: it seems to me you took  too serious statuses in social networks.

Comment: Yes I did which I know it's not good. I will trying to not pay attention on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Подруга** is most commonly used in the meaning of 'a female friend of another female' (but not a 'girlfriend'). In romantic relationship context, word подруга (or подружка) can often be used by a third person referring to someone's girlfriend, often with a certain level of disapproval or mockery. But I wouldn't normally call 'подруга' someone who I have romantic relationship with. If one wants to unambiguously convey the relationship meaning, he or she would call their girlfriend 'моя девушка' - there is no ambiguity in this expression.

Answer (score 1):

It's depends.

For example, it's very common for Russian speaking people to use “есть подруга” in Семейное положение just to show that they are good **friends**.

But yeh, usually (by grammar) it means that they are a couple.